# Different robots.txt for two different domains point to same folder

Tags: domains, htaccess, robots.txt, url-rewriting

I have the following two domains:

> `example.com`
>
> `test.example.com`

Both point to same folder which is `public_html`. What I want is a different `robots.txt` file for each domain. So when someone browse `example.com/robots.txt` then a different file is shown. And when someone go to `test.example.com/robots.txt` then a different file is shown.

How can I do this using URL rewriting in `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remeber that no one from Internet can see your directory tree, so `stackoverflow.com/` and `test.stackoverflow.com` are completely diffrent sites for us and search robots.

You can do that by checking the HTTP host in query:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test
RewriteRule robots.txt someotherrobots.txt
```

Comment: The example directive as posted would result in an internal rewrite-loop (500 error), since the rewritten URL `someotherrobots.txt` also matches the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ (regex) `robots.txt`. You need to make the _pattern_ more restrictive, perhaps with the use of _anchors_. For example: `RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ someotherrobots.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the earlier answer, you could use a single mod_rewrite rule to handle different `robots.txt` files for any number of subdomains.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite "robots.txt" to "robots-<subdomain>".txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www)([a-z]+)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots-%1.txt [L]
```

Any request for `<subdomain>.example.com/robots.txt` (except the `www` subdomain, as stated using the *negative lookahead* `(?!www)`) would be served by the corresponding `/robots-<subdomain>.txt` file. The `www` subdomain and the domain apex (ie. `example.com`) would be served by the default `robots.txt` file.

You could take this a step further and have the *subdomain's* `robots-<subdomain>.txt` file served "if it exists" and fallback to the default `robots.txt` file if it doesn't, by adding a filesystem check.

For example:

```
# Rewrite "robots.txt" to "robots-<subdomain>".txt if it exists
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www)([a-z]+)\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/robots-%1.txt -f
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots-%1.txt [L]
```

#### Prevent direct access to `robots-<subdomain>.txt`

To prevent direct access to the `/robots-<subdomain>.txt` file you can add an external redirect *before* the above rewrite. For example:

```
# Redirect direct requests to "robots-<subdomain>.txt" to "robots.txt" on <subdomain>
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^robots-([a-z]+)\.txt$ https://$1.example.com/robots.txt [R=301,L]
```

The above would redirect a direct request for `/robots-<subdomain>.txt` (regardless of the hostname being requested) to `https://<subdomain>.example.com/robots.txt`. The check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var ensures that only direct requests are redirected and not internally rewritten requests to `/robots-<subdomain>.txt`. Note that this uses the *filename* to determine the correct subdomain. eg. `https://foo.example.com/robots-bar.txt` would redirect to `https://bar.example.com/robots.txt` - changing the hostname, but ensures the same file is served.

To simply redirect to `/robots.txt` and keep the requested hostname. eg. `https://foo.example.com/robots-bar.txt` redirects to `https://foo.example.com/robots.txt` (which will result in `robots-foo.txt` being served by the above rewrite). Then the redirect can be simplified to:

```
# Redirect direct requests to "robots-<subdomain>.txt" to "robots.txt" on same host
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^robots-[a-z]+\.txt$ /robots.txt [R=301,L]
```

#### Summary

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect direct requests to "robots-<subdomain>.txt" to "robots.txt" on <subdomain>
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^robots-([a-z]+)\.txt$ https://$1.example.com/robots.txt [R=301,L]

# Rewrite "robots.txt" to "robots-<subdomain>".txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www)([a-z]+)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots-%1.txt [L]
```